# Bar Enash a designation of an authoritative representative of another?

Tags: commentaries, language, aramaic, daniel-book-of

Daniel 7:13. In that prophetic verse, Daniel declares that he sees one like a son of (mortal) man coming with clouds to the Ancient of Days to be presented before Him.

The expression ‘like a son of man’ here is Aramaic: k‘bar enash.

[Now Rabbi Shlomo Aharon Wertheimer (1866-1935) writes that the root of enosh (enash) is ish, with the additional NUN to serve as a diminutive].

**Are the words ‘bar enash’ a designation of an authoritative representative of another?** I’m asking this based on the following assumptions:

> Analyzing all the instances of ish in the Tenach one may conclude that
> ish is primarily a designation of affiliation, not an individual (like
> “person”). Certain semantic fields will evoke this noun’s contextual
> semantic domain of representation: ‘one who acts on behalf of others.’
> When the group in question is a corporate household (Israelite
> society’s basic unit of organization), its ish is its authoritative
> representative: the ‘householder’ or paterfamilias. Hence rendering
> ish in English as ‘man’ kind of distorts the text more than is usually
> recognized.
>
> If ish is primarily a noun of group affiliation representation, then
> any expression that implies individual gender identity is misleading.
> Since Aramaic and Hebrew are closely related sister languages from the
> same cultural base, we can be reasonably certain that the same
> societal assumptions are also true of Aramaic. Therefore, “son of man”
> is not a designation of an individual “person” who fulfills a divine
> role. **It is a designation of an authoritative representative of
> another**, just as a “man” is the authoritative representative of the
> household. The term enash or ish is a term designating the summary of
> relationships that result in representation of the unit. When Daniel
> uses the words bar enash (within the semantic domain of Israel), he is
> not suggesting that he saw a divine “person”, as some claim. Instead
> he’s claiming that, as Messiah, that person is the authorized
> representative of the Ancient of Days. The concept of “person”
> distorts this meaning, forcing one to interpret the text as if it
> included a Western idea of individual identity. In fact, the text
> suggests that the son of man is presented to the Ancient of Days
> precisely as the authoritative representative, perfectly consistent
> with the semantic domain in Hebrew/Aramaic thought.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the assumptions in your quotation are true. "Ish" translates very well as "man". It's basic meaning is a human male, but it can sometimes be used to represent a person in charge, e.g. man of the house. A simple [Sefaria search](https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A9&tab=text&tpathFilters=Tanakh&tvar=0&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance) of the word Ish will show that generally it just means a regular man, just as "Ishah" means a regular woman.

"Bar Enash" is just the Aramaic version of the very common Hebrew expression "Ben Adam", which means "son of man". See for example [this verse](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.8.5?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he&with=Aramaic%20Targum%20to%20Psalms&lang2=he) from Psalms with its Aramaic translation. And also [these verses](https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=%D7%91%D7%A8%20%D7%90%D7%A0%D7%A9&tab=text&tpathFilters=Targum&tvar=0&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance) from Jeremiah.

Comment: You assume that Bar-Enash is the equivalent of Ben-Adam, but I think it’s actually Bar-Adam בר אדם/ܒܪ ܐܕܡ, while the term Bar-Enash בר אנש/ܒܪ ܐܢܫ is probably connected to Ben-Enosh.

Comment: I don't assume; I demonstrated that in the authoritative Aramaic translations of the Bible, Bar Enash is a standard translation of Ben Adam. The word Adam never made it into Aramaic, so they used the word Enash instead.

Comment: The Targum of Ezekiel reads bar Adam. I’m not saying that Bar Enash isn’t used to translate Ben Adam outside of the Tenach, but it could be possible that in a verse like Daniel is was ment to emphasize the mortal man while the term ben Adam is often used to emphasize man's earthly origin or humanity.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/126413/bar-enash-what-whom-and-why/126427#126427